# std::discrete_distribution of a specified range of random numbers

Tags: c++, c++11, random, c++14

I know I can use [`std::discrete_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) like this:

```
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::discrete_distribution<int> distribution {2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2};

int p[10]={};

for (int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
    int number = distribution(generator);
    ++p[number];
}
```

However, this is going to generate the numbers in the range of 0-9 as per the weight specified.

What can I do to generate the numbers within a user specified range, say for example, 24-33 or 95-104 etc but still using the distribution specified in discrete_distribution ?

Comment: [0, n) + 10 == [10, n+10) Just use the distribution range as a base and add an offset.

Comment: you can just use that function and then do the mathematics, so let's say that function returns `[r1,r2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add 24 or 95 to the number that is generated. At the beginning you have numbers from 0 to 9, when you add 24 to them you have numbers from 24 to 33.

Answer (score -3):

when you have a function that returns a random number in range `[r1,r2)`, and you want `[min,max)` mathematics to help.

First we calculate `d=(max-min)/(r2-r1)` and then we multiply the range `[r1,r2)` by d so we get `[d*r1,d*r2)` which we'll make `[r1',r2')`, now you calculate `diff=abs(min-r1)'` and sum that to the range `[r1',r2')`, we used `abs` because we want the difference without sign, and that my friend will get you the range you want, let's assume the function that returns in range `[r1,r2)` is `somerand()` then :

```
const int r1=0,r2=9
int myrand(const int min,const int max){
    const int d=(max-min)/(r2-r1);
    const int localrand=d*somerand();
    return localrand + abs(min - d*r1);
}
```

you can check that the function returns `min` when `somerand()` returns `r1` and your function returns `max` when `somerand()` returns `r2`.

The solution above won't work with e.g. : r1=0,r2=2,min=0,max=3, in short `max-min` should be divisible by `r2-r1`.

Comment: That won't work, my nice man. Consider `r1=0`, `r2=1`, `min=0`, `max=2`. The problem is that the random numbers are after all **discrete**. Your *mathematics* assumed continuous random variables.

Comment: You say *in short `max-min` should be divisible by `r2-r1`*, but for `r1=0` `r2=1`, `min=0` `max=2`, `max-min` is divisible by `r2-r1` and yet it does not work. What you meant was presumably that *`r2-r1` should be divisible by `max-min`*. However, then your method fails too if the discrete probabilities are not the same. And if `r2-r1=max-min` we are at the case discussed in the other answers ...